# How to handle 'OverflowError: can't convert negative value to size_t' in rpi-rgb-led-matrix

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Trying to create an LED scoreboard with an RGB Matrix and a raspberry pi using API calls from online.

The Rpi is hosting a webpage that allows me to select which game I want to display on the RGB Matrix, however I am running into an issue after selecting a game which seems to stem from trying to display the team logos as if I remove that section of code the score displays fine.

Before adding the webpage

```
def run_code():
```

was not a defined function and everything ran perfectly displaying everything and playing goal gif animations, now inside a function along with the webpage it gives me the error:

```
OverflowError: can't convert negative value to size_t
```

here is the python code - its been shortened to not make it too long, hopefully I didn't omit anything crucial.

```
import time
import sys
import json
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
from rgbmatrix import RGBMatrix, RGBMatrixOptions, graphics
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
from sseclient import SSEClient
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/update_id', methods=['POST'])
def update_id():
    global ID
    ID = request.form['button_label']
    run_code()
    return 'ID updated to: {}'.format(ID)

def run_code():

    # Initialising the connection to the Squiggle API
    messages = SSEClient('https://api.squiggle.com.au/sse/events/' + ID)

    # Placeholder images, time and score strings
    hteamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Colours/Black")
    ateamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Colours/Black")
    timestr = "00:00"
    hteamscore = "00.00 000"
    ateamscore = "00.00 000"
    goal = "GOAL"
    # Load in font and select the colour
    font = graphics.Font()
    font.LoadFont("/home/pi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/fonts/tom-thumb.bdf")
    goalfont = graphics.Font()
    goalfont.LoadFont("/home/pi/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/fonts/10x20.bdf")
    WhiteText = graphics.Color(255, 255, 255)


    # Functions to display goal gif
    def get_frames(path):
        """Returns an iterable of gif frames."""
        frames = []
        with Image.open(path) as gif:
            for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(gif):
                frame = frame.convert('RGB').resize((64, 32))
                frames.append(frame)
            return frames


    def display_gif(path):
        """Displays gif frames on matrix."""
        options = RGBMatrixOptions()
        options.rows = 32
        options.cols = 64
        options.chain_length = 1
        options.parallel = 1
        options.hardware_mapping = 'adafruit-hat'
        matrix = RGBMatrix(options=options)
        
        for frame in get_frames(path):
            matrix.SetImage(frame)
            time.sleep(frame.info['duration']/1000)

    # Function for each teams goal display
    def AdelaideCrows():
        """Parses command line arguments."""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Display gif on LED matrix.')
        parser.add_argument('gif_path',
                            nargs='?',
                            metavar='PATH_TO_GIF',
                            type=Path,
                            default=Path(__file__).parent / 'AdelaideCrowsGoal.gif',
                            help='the path to the gif file')
        return parser
        
    def BrisbaneLions():
        """Parses command line arguments."""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Display gif on LED matrix.')
        parser.add_argument('gif_path',
                            nargs='?',
                            metavar='PATH_TO_GIF',
                            type=Path,
                            default=Path(__file__).parent / 'BrisbaneLionsGoal.gif',
                            help='the path to the gif file')
        return parser
        
    def Carlton():
        """Parses command line arguments."""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Display gif on LED matrix.')
        parser.add_argument('gif_path',
                            nargs='?',
                            metavar='PATH_TO_GIF',
                            type=Path,
                            default=Path(__file__).parent / 'CarltonGoal.gif',
                            help='the path to the gif file')
        return parser
            
    for msg in messages:
        # set RGB matrix options
        options = RGBMatrixOptions()
        options.rows = 32
        options.cols = 64
        options.chain_length = 1
        options.parallel = 1
        options.hardware_mapping = 'adafruit-hat'
        options.brightness = 50

        matrix = RGBMatrix(options=options)
        
        # Handle timestr event - Update game time
        if msg.event == 'timestr':
            data = json.loads(msg.data)
            timestr = data['timestr']           
            
        # Handle game event - set team logos and update scores if joined late
        if msg.event == 'game':
            data = json.loads(msg.data)
            timestr = data['timestr']
            hgoals = str(data['hgoals'])
            hbehinds = str(data['hbehinds'])
            hscore = str(data['hscore'])
            agoals = str(data['agoals'])
            abehinds = str(data['abehinds'])
            ascore = str(data['ascore'])
            hteamscore = hgoals + "." + hbehinds + " " + hscore
            ateamscore = agoals + "." + abehinds + " " + ascore
            
            # Set home team
            if data['hteam'] == 1:
                hteamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/AdelaideCrows")
                parser = AdelaideCrows()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                hgoal = args.gif_path
            elif data['hteam'] == 2:
                hteamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/BrisbaneLions")
                parser = BrisbaneLions()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                hgoal = args.gif_path
            elif data['hteam'] == 3:
                hteamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/Carlton")
                parser = Carlton()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                hgoal = args.gif_path
                
            # Set away team
            if data['ateam'] == 1:
                ateamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/AdelaideCrows")
                parser = AdelaideCrows()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                agoal = args.gif_path
            elif data['ateam'] == 2:
                ateamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/BrisbaneLions")
                parser = BrisbaneLions()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                agoal = args.gif_path
            elif data['ateam'] == 3:
                ateamlogo = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/AFLScoreboard/Logos/Carlton")
                parser = Carlton()
                args = parser.parse_args()
                agoal = args.gif_path
        
        # Handle score event - update game score, trigger goal display
        if msg.event == 'score':
            data = json.loads(msg.data)            
            if data['type'] == 'goal' and data['side'] == 'hteam':
                display_gif(hgoal)
            elif data['type'] == 'goal' and data['side'] == 'ateam':
                display_gif(agoal)
            score = data['score']
            hgoals = str(score['hgoals'])
            hbehinds = str(score['hbehinds'])
            hscore = str(score['hscore'])
            agoals = str(score['agoals'])
            abehinds = str(score['abehinds'])
            ascore = str(score['ascore'])
            hteamscore = hgoals + "." + hbehinds + " " + hscore
            ateamscore = agoals + "." + abehinds + " " + ascore
                

        # Set the size of team logos
        hteamlogo.thumbnail((32, 32), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        ateamlogo.thumbnail((32, 32), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Set the position of team logos, game time, game score
        matrix.SetImage(hteamlogo.convert('RGB'), -18, 1)
        matrix.SetImage(ateamlogo.convert('RGB'), 52, 1)
        graphics.DrawText(matrix, font, 15, 13, WhiteText, timestr)
        graphics.DrawText(matrix, font, 15, 19, WhiteText, hteamscore)
        graphics.DrawText(matrix, font, 15, 25, WhiteText, ateamscore)

    try:
        print("Press CTRL-C to stop.")
        while True:
            time.sleep(100)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

this is the HTML script with CSS and javascript functions - this has also been shortened

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AFL Scoreboard</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(224, 224, 130);
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          margin-left: 5px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
        h2 {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 36px;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
        h3 {
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }
        #button-container {
            position: fixed;
            top: 80px;
            left: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .round-button {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 120px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        .game-button {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        .content {
            display: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Live Games</h1>
    <button class="round-button" onclick="update_id('')">Live</button>
    <h1>Select a round</h1>
    <button id="btn-1" class="round-button" onclick="toggle_buttons('Round1')">Round 1</button>
    <button id="btn-2" class="round-button" onclick="toggle_buttons('Round2')">Round 2</button>

    <div id="Round1" class='content' style="display:none">
        <h2>Round 1</h2>
        <h3>Thursday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34260')">Richmond v Carlton</button>
        <h3>Friday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34261')">Geelong v Collingwood</button>
        <h3>Saturday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34262')">North Melbourne v West Coast</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34263')">Port Adelaide v Brisbane</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34264')">Gold Coast v Sydney</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34265')">Melbourne v Bulldogs</button>
        <h3>Sunday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34266')">GWS v Adelaide</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34267')">Hawthorn v Essendon</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34268')">St Kilda v Fremantle</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Round2" class='content' style="display:none">
        <h2>Round 2</h2>
        <h3>Thursday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34269')">Richmond v Carlton</button>
        <h3>Friday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34270')">Geelong v Collingwood</button>
        <h3>Saturday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34271')">North Melbourne v West Coast</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34272')">Port Adelaide v Brisbane</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34273')">Gold Coast v Sydney</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34274')">Melbourne v Bulldogs</button>
        <h3>Sunday</h3>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34275')">GWS v Adelaide</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34276')">Hawthorn v Essendon</button>
        <button class="game-button" onclick="update_id('34277')">St Kilda v Fremantle</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function toggle_buttons(id) {
            var x = document.getElementById(id);
            var btn = document.getElementById('btn-' + id);

            // Get all the button ids
            var btn_ids = ["1", "2"];

            // Loop through all the button ids and set their display to none,
            // except for the one that was clicked
            btn_ids.forEach(function(btn_id) {
              if (btn_id !== id.substr(-1)) {
                var other_x = document.getElementById("Round" + btn_id);
                other_x.style.display = "none";
                var other_btn = document.getElementById("btn-" + btn_id);
                other_btn.classList.remove("active");
              }
            });
          
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                btn.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                btn.classList.remove("active");
            }
        }
        function run_code() {
            fetch('/run_code')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the error that I recieve after running the python code and selecting a game to view

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Webpage/please.py", line 21, in update_id
    run_code()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Webpage/please.py", line 538, in run_code
    matrix.SetImage(hteamlogo.convert('RGB'), -18, 1)
  File "core.pyx", line 22, in rgbmatrix.core.Canvas.SetImage
    
  File "core.pyx", line 46, in rgbmatrix.core.Canvas.SetPixelsPillow
    
OverflowError: can't convert negative value to size_t
```

Comment: Are you sure about the instruction `matrix.SetImage(hteamlogo.convert('RGB'), -18, 1)`. The error speaks about `negative value` and in the previous instruction I can see the number `-18`. Furthermore the previous instruction is part of the error message.

Comment: Changing it to a positive results in the exact same error. When the run_code() is run in isolation outside of the function it works perfectly with only half the image being displayed (which is intended) but all together this error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue by calling `SetImage` with `unsafe=False`

`matrix.SetImage(hteamlogo.convert('RGB'), -18, 1, unsafe=False)`

This has to be done for everytime `SetImage` is called in the code.